# How do I this shell (.zsh) script to put files into nested folders?

Tags: shell, pdf, zsh, libreoffice

This script takes files from nested folders and mass converts them to PDF. This part works fine. The problem is that the PDFs generated are put into the parent folder only - and I want each one to end up in the folder it was originally found in.

```
#!/bin/zsh

source_dir="/source/folder/of/documents"

input_file_types=(doc docx xls xlsx)
output_file_type="PDF"

echo "# Using source directory " "$source_dir"
echo "# Converting "$input_file_types" to "$output_file_type

# loop over the types and convert
for input_file_types in "${input_file_types[@]}"
do
        # Find the files and pipe the results into the read command.  The read command properly handles spaces in directories and files names.
        # find "$source_dir" -name *.$input_file_type | while read in_file
        find "$source_dir" -name "*.$input_file_types" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' in_file
        # In order to correctly handle filenames containing whitespace and newline characters, you should use null delimited output. That's what the -print0 and read -d $'\0' is for.
        do
                echo "Processing…"
                echo "> Input "$in_file

                # Convert the file
                sudo /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir "$source_dir" $in_file

                echo "> Finished "$out_file "\n\n"
        done
done

echo "DONE CONVERTING FILES"
```

I know that the problem lies in the --outdir "$source_dir" command, but I'm unsure of what to replace that with so the file shows up in the nested folder the file was found in.

Note that I have attempted to remove the --outdir "$source_dir" command entirely - but that just dumps the resulting PDF files into the folder the script was run from.

Comment: Did you check, that the variable `source_dir` has as value the directory where you want the PDF to be stored into? If it does, the problem is in your use `soffice` and not in the logic of your script. If this is the casd, please ask about how to use `soffice` correctly at [su].

Answer (score 1):

In `zsh`, the `:h` modifier will get the directory from a filename, so that can be used to set the output location:

```bash
--outdir "${in_file:h}"
```

There are some other shell operators available that can shorten the loop a bit, while still supporting filenames with spaces and newlines:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
source_dir="/source/folder/of/documents"
input_file_types=(doc docx xls xlsx)

file_pattern="${source_dir}/*.(${(j:|:)input_file_types})"
for in_file in ${~file_pattern}; do
    /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice \
        --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export \
        --outdir "${in_file:h}" \
        "${in_file}"
done
```

Note that this does not use `sudo`; that shouldn't be necessary when dealing with files like this. If the command will not work without sudo, that may indicate a directory permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out:

```
#!/bin/zsh

source_dir="/source/folder/of/documents"

input_file_types=(doc docx xls xlsx)
output_file_type="PDF"

echo "# Using source directory " "$source_dir"
echo "# Converting "$input_file_types" to "$output_file_type

# loop over the types and convert
for input_file_types in "${input_file_types[@]}"
do
        # Find the files and pipe the results into the read command.  The read command properly handles spaces in directories and files names.
        # find "$source_dir" -name *.$input_file_type | while read in_file
        find "$source_dir" -name "*.$input_file_types" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' in_file
        # In order to correctly handle filenames containing whitespace and newline characters, you should use null delimited output. That's what the -print0 and read -d $'\0' is for.
        do
                echo "Processing…"
                echo "> Input: "$in_file

                file_path="${in_file%/*}/"
                echo "> File path: "$file_path

                # Convert the file
                echo "*** Converting "$in_file
                sudo /Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir "$file_path" $in_file

                echo "> Finished: "$out_file "\n\n"
        done
done

echo "DONE CONVERTING FILES"
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**